# How to create different post layout for different categories and subcategories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've modified the single.php file in order to change layout for each category. In single.php I have this code

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category( '26') ||  get_term_children('26') {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-ric.php');
}
elseif ( in_category( '36') ||  get_term_children('36') {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-parl.php');
}
else {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-all.php');
}
?>
```

Is there something wrong in this code? 
Each post article is shown with single-ric.php layout

Comment: Use `get_template_part( 'single', 'all' );` in stead of `include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-all.php');`. Never use `TEMPLATEPATH`, it is due for depreciation (*if hasn't yet being depreciated*)

Comment: if I use 'get_template_part( 'single', 'all' );' the page shows only the header not the content. I have all the single.php, single-parl.php, single-all.php and single-ric.php in the same folder.

Comment: `get_template_part` fail silently if he can't find the template, so you probably have an other error. Activate debug mode (change `WP_DEBUG` constant in _wp-config.php_ to true) and see if any error shows up.

Comment: I just thought that as `get_template_part` use the slug as fallback, he may include `single.php` if he don't find your parts - so he could create an include loop and explain why it break.

Comment: I enabled the debug but still blank page, no error shown

Comment: What Wordpress version do you use?

Comment: @vard the version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Your question address few issues. First, as Pieter stated, you should use [`get_template_part`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) instead of `TEMPLATEPATH` as [it is deprecated](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298).

What you need to do is to rename your templates to something like `singlepost-ric.php`, `singlepost-parl.php` and `singlepost.php` (instead of `singlepost-all.php` - that will be your fallback), this to prevent any fallback loop conflict - you need to place them at the same level as `single.php` to make this work. Then, use `get_template_part` in this way:

```
get_template_part('singlepost', 'ric');
```

If this doesn't work, use this to get the possible error messages:

```
assert("locate_template( array('singlepost-ric.php', 'singlepost.php'), false, false )");
```

The other issue is, and why your first condition is always true, is that you don't use right [`get_term_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children). This function is used to get all the childrens of a term in a single array. If it don't find any, it will return an empty array, not `false`. This is why this `(in_category( '26') ||  get_term_children('26'))` is always true. By the way, you're missing a closing parenthesis in all your conditions.

I assume that what you want to do, is to know if the current post is in the category `26`. Just remove the `get_term_children` part - it address something else. You probably added this because a category is a taxonomy, which would be valid then, but `in_category` is enough.

Last thing, you don't need this:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
```

It is redundant. As you're within a template, the global var `$post` already contains the post you query.

Comment: I followed your answer, but I still have blank page, where can I put              'assert("locate_template( array('singlepost-ric.php', 'singlepost.php'), false, false )");' ? Another thing is that I need that all the post belonging to cat 26 and sub categories have the same layout

Comment: Just use `assert` in your template - it will return `true` if `locate_template` can find the template, `false` otherwise. For category, `in_category(26)` is enough for posts that belong to this category. For child categories, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7615/62744).